# Tracking down a memory leak

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, memory, debugging, memory-leak

I previously asked a [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/700303/80-memory-utilization-on-server-is-this-just-caching/700387#700387) about a server that had a very high nonpaged pool memory utilization and someone explained how to use poolmon to track down the problem driver.

I did this, but I'm not sure I have identified the issue.

Running poolmon:
[image]

Now searching for fwpx I only got one "match":
[image]

dsac.exe? The AD administrative center is causing the memory leak?- that obviously can't be right, but that was the only match findstr found.

Googling the fwpx pool tag I can see some issues people had with the McAfee anti-virus product (but Symantec SEP is install on this server).

According to [this Technet blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/yongrhee/archive/2009/06/24/pool-tag-list.aspx) post the fwpx pool tag is the related to this driver:
Fwpx - fwpkclnt.sys - WFP NBL tagged context

But if that is the case why didn't findstr locate it?

Then I googled more and found this kb:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2885980

According to the kb the FwpsAllocateCloneNetBufferlist() API leaks memory- awesome.

But I'm still not 100% this is the issue. Before installing the hot-fix how can I confirm this problem is caused by this WFP bug? I would assume its SEP that is using the buggy WFP API. This makes sense because I saw McAfee users (another AV product that might be using the API) having similar memory leak issues.

But to be sure, how can I identify the program that is calling the WFP API- if that is what is actually even happening.

Comment: according to the pooltag.txt from the SDK, the fwpx tag belongs to fwpkclnt.sys (Fwpx - fwpkclnt.sys - WFP NBL tagged context). We need to capture a xperf trace of the pool usage **GROW**: http://pastebin.com/fvugmGtP. The Win8.1 SDK works on Server 2008R2, but not for the original 2008. Here you have to use the Windows 7 SDK.

Comment: have you captured a trace? If you can't share it, follow this guide: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-48-WPT-Memory-Analysis-Pool

Comment: any progress? does the hotfix fixes the issue? or have you captured the trace?

Comment: Didn't have time to do a trace (but useful info). Just installed the patch and confirmed it was no longer leaking memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't have time to follow what magicandre1981 suggested, but was able to confirm that the [patch solved](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2885980) the issue. Maybe this will be helpful to others that have a similar memory leak issue.

Another thing we noticed: running a full Windows update seems to include this fix, but in some other patch. After we ran a full windows update on another server with this issue (instead of applying the specific patch) the patch would not install throwing a very unhelpful "this patch does not apply to this platform" sort of error. It turns out this issue was resolve in some other update.

So I guess applying the patch or making sure the server is completely updated will solve the `FwpsAllocateCloneNetBufferlist()` API leak.